# Easiest way to ensure same font and font size in labels, input boxes and text areas

Tags: css

I have a page where I combine labels, input boxes and text areas to display some content.
I would like all of them to have the same font-family and font-size. 
I have played with the *font-family: inherit* style but this doesn't seem to work for the input and text areas.
What would be the easiest way to ensure the same font / size over the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok ... this does the trick:

```
*
{
    font-family: arial;
}

input
{
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%
}

textarea
{
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My CSS is iffy as I haven't used it in some time, but I believe doing

```
*
{
    font-family: arial;
}
```

will apply to all.

Comment: Nope .. the font in input box-es doesn't change.

Comment: Something must be overriding it then later.  I just tried it on a web-page that was bare except for that style and an input and it resized it.

Comment: Can be ... my page is really complex in design and style.

Comment: I will mark this as correct, as it helped solving the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think most CSS devs will do something like

```
body {font: normal 10pt Arial}
```

At the top of the CSS file.

If you want to change labels from this, just add a

```
label, input, textarea {font-family:Georgia}
```

somewhere down the road.

Comment: the input and text areas will still have their own fonts.

Comment: Ah, I think I slightly misunderstood her question.  Editing.